# how do i do a nested while statement after an while in python?

Tags: python

```
print("Please enter a number")
Numbered_Being_Entered_Input = input()
Numbered_Being_Entered = int(Numbered_Being_Entered_Input)
Accumulated_Number = 0
while Numbered_Being_Entered > 0:
    print("The number you have entered is ", Numbered_Being_Entered)
    Accumulated_Number = Numbered_Being_Entered + Accumulated_Number
    print("The accumulated sum of all the numbers you have entered is ", Accumulated_Number)
    Numbered_Being_Entered_Input = input()
    Numbered_Being_Entered = int(Numbered_Being_Entered_Input)
if Numbered_Being_Entered < 0:
    print("you have chosen the number 0 or a negative number")
    print("Please enter a number higher than 0")
    print("The accumulated sum of all the numbers you have entered before this error is ", Accumulated_Number)
    Numbered_Being_Entered_Input = input()
    Numbered_Being_Entered = int(Numbered_Being_Entered_Input)
```

How can I make a code, that if a number 0 or less has been inputted, the user can still make input and still retain the accumulated numbers.

The assignment is:

Prepare pseudocode for a program that lets a user continuously enter numbers until a number less than or equal to 0 is entered. Display the number of numbers entered AND the sum of those numbers.

Prepare a Python program that implements item the assignment above. Make sure you test it with several numbers. Turn in your Python source code as well as the output from your Python program

Comment: Could you change the variable name be more short? It's really hard to read.

Comment: You only learn if you do your own homework.

Comment: Looks like you already created an `if` after the `while` loop. What is your question then ?

Comment: @alfasin I meant to do a while statement after a while statement.

Comment: @alfasin how do I nest a while after me putting Number_being_Entered > 0:

Comment: @NickBailey this class isn't to learn python.

Comment: What do you specifically want your program to *do* that it doesn't do currently?

Comment: Please focus your question on *what* do you want to do, not on *how* do you want to do it. As of right now - it's still not clear to me what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Tulio, your code achieves your problem definition. If you think that you want to again take input numbers after user submits 0 or -ve number then thats not what your problem definition means. Your program should end once user submits 0 or -ve number

Comment: @MohitChandak Thanks.

Comment: If you question is resolved, please mark the answer as the correct one so future visitors to this page know that it has been resolved.

Comment: Click the checkbox underneath the arrows to the left of the answer and the checkmark will turn green.

Comment: @leb lol. I had the number lock unlocked and thought I was inputting numbers. I was just clicking enter without numbers and why I was getting that error. my bad.

Comment: @Jesse thanks. I didn't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print("Please enter a number")
Numbered_Being_Entered_Input = input()
Numbered_Being_Entered = int(Numbered_Being_Entered_Input)
Accumulated_Number = 0

while True:
    if Numbered_Being_Entered > 0:
        print("The number you have entered is ", Numbered_Being_Entered)
        Accumulated_Number = Numbered_Being_Entered + Accumulated_Number
        print("The accumulated sum of all the numbers you have entered is ", Accumulated_Number)
        Numbered_Being_Entered_Input = input()
        Numbered_Being_Entered = int(Numbered_Being_Entered_Input)
    elif Numbered_Being_Entered <= 0:
        print("you have chosen the number 0 or a negative number")
        print("Please enter a number higher than 0")
        print("The accumulated sum of all the numbers you have entered before this error is ", Accumulated_Number)
        Numbered_Being_Entered_Input = input()
        Numbered_Being_Entered = int(Numbered_Being_Entered_Input)
```

1) Don't do the comparison at the `while` you'll terminate the program when it's done and you can't proceed. Right off the bat the `while` will cause problems because `0>0` is `False`

2) You need to define what happens when they enter `0` so far you define all real numbers except `0` hence there's a `<=`

```
Please enter a number
1
The number you have entered is  1
The accumulated sum of all the numbers you have entered is  1
2
The number you have entered is  2
The accumulated sum of all the numbers you have entered is  3
0
you have chosen the number 0 or a negative number
Please enter a number higher than 0
The accumulated sum of all the numbers you have entered before this error is  3
1
The number you have entered is  1
The accumulated sum of all the numbers you have entered is  4
```

Comment: this helps so much. I didn't knew about the --While True-- statement. This exactly what I wanted to do, but I didn't knew how to do an if and else statement after the while statement. :)

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciated the help.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
, line 3, in <module>
    Numbered_Being_Entered = int(Numbered_Being_Entered_Input)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: What number were you entering?

Comment: I had the number lock unlocked and thought I was inputting numbers. I was just clicking enter without numbers and why I was getting that error. my bad. lol

Comment: No worries. Also note that you'll get that error for floats. So if you input 1.5 you'll get the same `ValueError` because you're doing `int()` for the `input()`

Comment: I would use the float()? For a decimal.

Comment: Yes, and format the number of decimal points to prevent long numbers after decimal point